# How to implement inAppBrowser Back Button in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I have an Ionic App where from side menu click it will go to page A and from there on certain action it will go to Page B and I need back button on all the pages which will navigate it back to mobile app.

I tried this code

```
$scope.goOut= function () {
        //$scope.showLoading($ionicLoading);
        var url = "https://www.google.com";
        var target = '_blank';
         var options = ['location=no','hardwareback=yes','toolbarposition=top', 'toolbar=yes','enableViewportScale=yes',
        'transitionstyle=fliphorizontal',
        'closebuttoncaption=Back to the App'];

        var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options.join());
        ref.addEventListener("loadstop",function () {
           $scope.hide($ionicLoading);
        });
    };
```

But this is not showing me anything on the inappbrowser.
I must be doing something horribly wrong? and its not even showing loading?

Comment: Use cordoba-plugin-themeablebrowser.

Comment: Is there a way to post a form through cordova.themeablebrowser?

Comment: See full documentation of theme able browser https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser